# Variável local que referencia para o mesmo objeto de uma variável global é alterada, mas a global não

Tags: python

Tenho o seguinte problema: Estou fazendo uma Árvore Rubro-Negra em Python, e quando vou excluir uma raíz que tenha um só filho, acontece o problema, abaixo segue meu código

```
BLACK = 0
RED = 1

class No():

    def __init__(self, valor, pai=None, esquerda=None, direita=None, cor=RED):
        self.valor = valor
        self.esquerda = esquerda
        self.direita = direita
        self.pai = pai
        if pai == None:
            self.cor = BLACK
        else:
            self.cor = cor

    def filho_nao_nulo(self):
        return (self.direita if self.direita != None else self.esquerda)

    def remover(self, valor):
        #global raiz
        no = self
        if no == None:
            return None
        if valor < no.valor:
            no.esquerda.remover(valor)
        elif valor > no.valor:
            no.direita.remover(valor)
        else:
            #o nó encontrado só tem um filho
            if no.direita != None or no.esquerda != None:
                if no.cor == BLACK:
                        #se o nó é a raiz
                        if no.pai == None:
                            if no.esquerda == no.filho_nao_nulo():
                                no = no.esquerda
                                no.cor = BLACK
                            else:
                                no = no.direita
                                no.cor = BLACK                          

raiz = No(12)
raiz.direita = No(14, raiz)
raiz.remover(12)
```

Ao chegar na linha

```
no = no.direita
```

o debug está dessa maneira:

[image: Debug]

Ao executar essa linha, apenas a variável local "no" é alterada, mas a global "raiz" não, sendo que ambas se referenciam ao mesmo endereço de memória

[image: o nó passa a ter o endereço de memória da direita da raiz]

o nó passa a ter o endereço de memória da direita da raiz, como deveria ser feito com a raiz, mas a raiz não é alterada.

O mais estranho é que isso só acontece com a raiz, se o nó, por exemplo fosse igual a raiz.direita.esquerda, não haveria problema nenhum com qualquer operação que eu quisesse fazer sobre esse nó, ele alteraria tanto a variável local, como a global.

Tive um problema semelhante na árvore AVL.

A solução temporária que tive foi declarar o código

```
global raiz
```

no início do método, e mudar a raiz diretamente. Mas li sobre, e vi que isso não é uma boa prática. Alguém poderia me ajudar ? Obrigado.

Comment: Preencha a parte que tem o "#bloco de código", pois sem ela, não dá para reproduzir o problema. E coloque a parte da classe `No` necessária a isso. De resto, a sua pergunta me parece estar legal.

Comment: Certo, vou tentar adicionar todo o código.

Comment: Acabei de adicionar Victor, agora você deve conseguir executar o código.

Comment: Importante [edit] a pergunta e reduzir o código a um [mcve] do problema.

Comment: Pronto, o código agora está bem enxuto e executável, mas acredito que não consigo retirar as imagens, com elas fica bem mais claro o que está acontecendo no debug.